# Serenity/WebDriver: cannot access localhost

Tags: java, webdriver, localhost, serenity-bdd

I have problems with Serenity/WebDriver. Suddenly one day, my code doesn't work and I got the error "Unknown host localhost".

I can reproduced with the code from http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_serenity_with_cucumber:

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class WhenSearchingOnGoogle {

    @Managed                                                                
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void shouldInstantiateAWebDriverInstanceForAWebTest() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");                                

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("firefly", Keys.ENTER);

        new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(titleContains("Google Search"));

        assertThat(driver.getTitle()).isEqualTo("firefly - Google Search");
    }
}
```

I got this error:

### TEST STARTED: shouldInstantiateAWebDriverInstanceForAWebTest

18:06:11.599 [main] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST NUMBER: 1
sept. 22, 2018 6:06:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFOS: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`

net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: localhost could not be reached

```
at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.RemoteDriverBuilder.newRemoteDriver(RemoteDriverBuilder.java:66)
at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.DefaultRemoteDriver.buildWithOptions(DefaultRemoteDriver.java:24)
at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.RemoteDriverProvider.newInstance(RemoteDriverProvider.java:53)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:127)
at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:149)
```

I do not understand the "localhost could not be reached" when I give another URL ?!

I tried others drivers with no success.
How can I make it work ?

Thks,
Cédric

Comment: It seems that i have to start the Selenium server Hub, but I do not remember having started it when it worked, some days ago.
Is it possible that Serenity start the Selenium server ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a remote webdriver was used, with localhost:4444, certainly by this parameter in serenity.properties:
webdriver.remote.url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

i solved this with https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/README.md#selenium-grid-hub-and-nodes:
creating a docker-compose.yml, then 
starting with docker compose up -d
stopping with docker-compose down

Comment: if you start the selenium grid it will give what url you have to use for connecting to grid. pasting the logs from the console - ------ 

    11:23:57.410 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
    11:23:57.425 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://10.45.30.151:4444/grid/register/
11:23:57.425 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://10.45.30.151:4444/wd/hub
11:24:05.265 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://10.45.30.151:39797

Answer (score 0):

If you run the selenium server locally its simple

```
1. Please download the binary from
```

[Selenium downloads page](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Now navigate to the folder contains the jar and open command prompt there and run the commands in step 2 and 3

2 . Start hub :

```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub
```

3. Register:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

After that you have to find the matching drivers for the version of chrome. for example v69 using chromdriver version 2.42.